# how can i know from where double free or corruption (out) error is coming?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <climits>
using namespace std;
#define MAX_WEIGHT 1000000
class Set
{
public:
    int * parent;
    int * height;

    Set(int _n)
    {
        parent = new int[_n+1];
        height = new int[_n+1];
        for(int i=0; i<_n+1; i++)
        {
            parent[i] = i;
            height[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    ~Set()
    {
        delete[] parent;
        delete[] height;
    }

    int Find_Set(int _x)
    {
        while(parent[_x]!=_x)
        {
            _x = parent[_x];
        }
        return _x;
    }

    void Union_Set(int _x, int _y)
    {
        _x = Find_Set(_x);
        _y = Find_Set(_y);
        if(_x!=_y)
        {
            if(height[_x]>height[_y])
                parent[_y] = _x;
            else if(height[_x]<height[_y])
                parent[_x] = _y;
            else
            {
                parent[_y] = _x;
                height[_x]++;
            }
        }
    }
};
template<typename WEIGHT_TYPE>
class Graph
{
public:
    int vNum; // num of vertices
    int eNum; // num of edges
    vector<pair<int, WEIGHT_TYPE>> * edges;

    Graph(const char * _fileName)
    {
        FILE * input = fopen(_fileName, "r");
        fscanf(input, "%d %d", &vNum, &eNum);
        edges = new vector<pair<int, WEIGHT_TYPE>>[vNum];

        for(int i=0; i<eNum; i++)
        {
            int idx1, idx2;
            double weight;
            fscanf(input, "%d %d %lf", &idx1, &idx2, &weight);
            idx1--;
            idx2--;

            edges[idx1].push_back(make_pair(idx2, weight));
            edges[idx2].push_back(make_pair(idx1, weight));
        }
    }

    ~Graph()
    {
        delete[] edges;
    }
};
template<typename WEIGHT_TYPE>
WEIGHT_TYPE Kruskal(Graph<WEIGHT_TYPE> &_graph)
{
    vector<pair<WEIGHT_TYPE, pair<int, int>>> k;
    for(int i=0; i<_graph.vNum; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<_graph.edges[i].size(); j++)
        {
            if(_graph.edges[i][j].second==-1)
                continue;
            if(i<_graph.edges[i][j].first)
                k.push_back(make_pair(_graph.edges[i][j].second, make_pair(i, _graph.edges[i][j].first)));
        }
    }
    sort(k.begin(), k.end());
    WEIGHT_TYPE cost = (WEIGHT_TYPE)0;
    Set s(_graph.vNum);

    for(int i=0; i<k.size(); i++)
    {
        int idx1 = k[i].second.first;
        int idx2 = k[i].second.second;
        WEIGHT_TYPE weight = k[i].first;

        if(s.Find_Set(idx1) != s.Find_Set(idx2))
        {
            s.Union_Set(idx1, idx2);
            cost += weight;
        }
    }
    return cost;
}
template<typename WEIGHT_TYPE>
WEIGHT_TYPE Second(Graph<WEIGHT_TYPE> _graph)
{
    WEIGHT_TYPE cost = (WEIGHT_TYPE)INT_MAX;
    WEIGHT_TYPE cost2 = (WEIGHT_TYPE)INT_MAX;
    WEIGHT_TYPE result = (WEIGHT_TYPE)INT_MAX;
    for(int from=0; from<_graph.eNum; from++)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<_graph.edges[from].size(); i++)
        {
            int to = _graph.edges[from][i].first;
            for(int j=0; j<_graph.edges[to].size(); j++)
            {
                if(_graph.edges[to][j].first==from)
                {
                    int tmp1 = _graph.edges[from][to].second;
                    int tmp2 = _graph.edges[to][j].second;
                    _graph.edges[from][to].second = -1;
                    _graph.edges[to][j].second = -1;
                    result = Kruskal(_graph);
                    printf("RESULT : %d\n", result);
                    if(result<cost)
                    {
                        cost2 = cost;
                        cost = result;
                    }
                    else if(result>cost && result<cost2)
                    {
                        cost2 = result;
                    }
                    _graph.edges[from][to].second = tmp1;
                    _graph.edges[to][j].second = tmp2;
                    printf("SECOND : %d\n", cost2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return cost2;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Graph<int> g(argv[1]);
    //int cost = Kruskal<int>(g);
    int cost2 = Second<int>(g);
    printf("cost2: %d\n", cost2);   
    FILE * output = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    fprintf(output, "%d", cost2);
}
```

well I have this code and my input file as

```
7 12
1 2 8
1 3 5
2 3 10
2 4 2
2 5 18
3 4 3
3 6 16
4 5 12
4 6 30
4 7 14
5 7 4
6 7 26
```

I searched the web for this error and found out that it's caused when you delete a free a memory that was never allocated or already deleted or freed from memory. But I don't see any part of my code that frees or delete those kind of empty memory.. I also tried to use GDB but due to my poor knowledge, i just figured out that it was caused at Kruskal() in Second() in main().... nothing else.. So what i want to know is which in my code causes the error and how can i track it?

Comment: How do you invoke the program? What needs to be on the command line?

Comment: The best solution is to not have pointers to begin with. If you need a "dynamic array" use `std::vector` instead. If pointers are needed due to some requirement, then use *smart pointers* like e.g. [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). And always follow the [rules of three, five or zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) (the rule of zero is preferred).

Comment: As for finding memory problems, then tools such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) are very helpful.

Comment: If I run this in debug mode, `int tmp1 = _graph.edges[from][to].second;` yields in a _vector subscript out of range_. CHeck here first

Comment: clang introduced "address sanitizer" which later gcc also incorporated. This is much more efficient tool than Valgrind (which is nice, but painful).

Comment: `new` should not occur anywhere in your code. `new vector` is especially unnecessary.

Comment: thanks very much!! I should definitely learn how to use Valgrind after this semester.... solved lots of problems thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not observing the rule of 5: If you manually define any of the five special member functions (destructor, copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment, move assignment), you should define all five explicitly because the auto-generated ones are most likely wrong.

This is exactly the case here:

Your class has an implicitly-defined copy constructor (which copies the pointer member). You invoke this copy constructor when you call `WEIGHT_TYPE Second(Graph<WEIGHT_TYPE> _graph)` - the argument is copied. Now you have two copies of the same `Graph`, **both with a pointer to the same array of `vector`**. The one that goes out of scope first (at the end of `Second`) will `delete[]` that pointer... But eventually the program ends, the `Graph` in `main` will go out of scope and will `delete[]` the pointer again! That's a double free.

This is why you should aim to follow the rule of zero: Never do explicit resource management. Don't use `new` and `delete`, use smart pointers or container classes. The compiler will auto-generate the correct operations (and forbid those that make no sense - if your class has explicit ownership of a pointer, i.e. std::unique_ptr, it cannot be copied).

Further reading: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Comment: Oh.... I get it.. I see what's the problem now! Thank you very much for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

To fix memory issues there are couple tools:

- Address sanitizer - best supported by clang and gcc
- valgrind - good to, but slow, works on gcc and clang
- electric fence
- many others

As you you are writing Grpah and you have memory issues, [this cppCon](https://youtu.be/JfmTagWcqoE) is a must for you.

In general

- do not use raw pointers and manual memory management at all.
- use `std::unique_ptr` and raw pointer as weak counterpart
- or use `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr`

If you use this rules that rule of zero will do the job in most cases.

Note that Herb Sutter present also a concept of container which can do a graphs. It has some sort of garbage collection, here is his [repo](https://github.com/hsutter/gcpp).

Comment: Thanks for the advice! the video was also VERY helpful!